# nginx conditional proxy pass

Tags: proxy, nginx

i am trying to configure nginx to proxy pass the request to another server, 
only if the $request_body variable matches on a specific regular expression.

My problem now is, that I don't how to configure this behaviour exactly.

I am currently down to this one:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name test.local;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

            if ($request_body ~* ^(.*)\.test) {
                    proxy_pass http://www.google.de;
            }

            root /srv/http;
    }

}
```

but the problem here is, that root has always the upperhand. 
the proxy won't be passed either way.

any idea on how I could accomplish this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to check `$request_body` against regexp? It will slow your app for x times

Also, do you want to do `proxy_pass` or just `redirect` ?

Comment: yeah i have no other choice, unfortunately, and I really need to proxy pass, the application cannot redirect (xml-rpc client)

Comment: But what's the problem now? Isn't working? What's in logs?

Comment: yeah it is not working, when i remove the root line, the proxy works, when I add the root line, it's as if the proxy is not configured at all.

Comment: so I somehow need to manage to make the if working as i would expect it to...

Comment: nothing special, when root is set, it says page not found when i go on test.local/fish.test (which would match against the regexp, i replaced request_body with uri for testing) but when i remove the line root /srv/http it only redirect. logs aren't helpful at this point

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nginx routing is based on the location directive which matches on the Request URI. The solution is to temporarily modify this in order to forward the request to different endpoints.

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name test.local;

     if ($request_body ~* ^(.*)\.test) {
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /istest/$1;
     }

     location / {
         root /srv/http;
     }

     location /istest/ {
        rewrite ^/istest/(.*)$  $1 break;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://www.google.de;

    }
}
```

The `if` condition can only safely be used in Nginx with the [rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) which it is part of. In this example. The `rewrite` prefixes the Request URI with `istest`.

The `location` blocks give precedence to the closest match. Anything matching `/istest/` will go to the second block which uses another `rewrite` to remove `/istest/` from the Request URI before forwarding to the upstream proxy.

Comment: With this solution, users could also directly access /istest/, circumventing the "if" check. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Clients could access the /istest/ path just by including the required string in the request body - so this is not about preventing access to the path. The upstream server should validate the request if it is untrusted.  However a hard fail might be enforced with `set $my_upstream http://www.google.de;` within the condition and `proxy_pass $my_upstream;` in the location block.

Answer (score 21):

try this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name test.local;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        if ($request_body ~* ^(.*)\.test) {
            proxy_pass http://www.google.de;
            break;
        }

        root /srv/http;
    }

}
```

Comment: thx man, you saved me a lot of time and headache, i'm glad the solution was this simple :D much appreciated!

Comment: @sharpner Does this method still work? It doesn't appear to in my testing.

Comment: @user973254 did you actually test this? It looks like nginx doesn't read the request_body variable at this point, so it never passes the check...

Comment: it does not work anymore. The only thing that's still correct in the answer, is the missing break from the original version. - I "unaccepted" the answer.