# nginx conditional proxy pass with different context

Tags: nginx

My problem is that i have several primary servers like:

```
192.168.0.100/service
192.168.0.101/service
```

and one backup server like:

```
192.168.0.102/serviceInternal
```

Nginx is listening on:

```
192.168.0.200:8000
```

Config file looks like:

```
upstream sth {
         server 192.168.0.100:8001; #primary server
         server 192.168.0.101:8001; #primary server
         server 192.168.0.102:8001 backup; #backup server
}

server {
         listen   192.168.0.200:8000;

         location /service {
                 if ( primary_servers = up ) {
                        proxy_pass sth/service;
                 }
                 if ( primary_servers = down ) {
                        proxy_pass sth/serviceInternal;
                 }
         }
}
```

I hope i presented my problem in quite clear way :)

Comment: Could you formulate a question? What is not working and what do you like to achieve?

Comment: the main problem is in conditions about primary servers. If primary servers are online i would like to forward traffic to /service endpoint if they are not online i would like to forward traffic to /serviceInternal endpoint on backup server.

Comment: Did you have a look at other questions on SA? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878334/nginx-conditional-proxy-pass?rq=1) might help maybe?

Comment: Yes, I have searched SA and I think it is not a solution for my problem because request_body will be always the same. What I need is check primary servers if the are online or not.

Comment: If they all would be `/service` (not `/serviceInternal`) then simple `proxy_pass http://sth/service;` would do what you want.

Comment: I they all would be `/service` I wouldn't ask the question ;)

Comment: Probably I would use "fake" server for backup

Answer (score 2):

I would use "fake" server for backup

```
upstream sth {
         server 192.168.0.100:8001; #primary server
         server 192.168.0.101:8001; #primary server
         server 127.0.0.1:8001 backup; #backup server
}

upstream sth_backup {
         server 192.168.0.102:8001;
}

# fake server for URI replace
server {
         listen 127.0.0.1:8001;
         location /service {
                 proxy_pass http://sth_backup/serviceInternal;
         }

server {
         listen   192.168.0.200:8000;

         location /service {
                 proxy_pass http://sth/service;
         }
}
```

Comment: wow, I'm impressed :) Really nice workaround :) Thanks a lot @AlexeyTen