# Configure NGINX SNI to use different header than 'Host'

Tags: nginx, header, host, sni

I have a working NGINX configuration with SNI enabled and I am able to server two different SSL Certificates based on the incoming request **Host** header.

What I would need is to be able to configure NGINX to use a different header and not use **Host** for this 'routing' done based on the header. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: SNI is part of TLS negotiation, which occurs before the HTTP request is sent. There is no HTTP header involvement in SNI. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In the NGINX configuration I created two servers with two different server names: `server_name Test1;` and `server_name Test2`. When I make a request with header `Host: Test1` I get the SSL certificate from that server, If I make a request with header `Host: Test2` I get the SSL certificate from the 2nd server. All of this is working ok for me, but I am wondering if I can use a different header, different from Host to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Host header isn't used to determine which certificate you get from the server.

The TLS handshake begins with a ClientHello, and your client provides the hostname (SNI) as a part of this handshake. The server then responds with the correct certificate. (In the case of NGINX, if you request a server name it doesn't know about, it will respond with the first certificate defined in its configuration.)

After the TLS setup, your client makes an HTTP request which includes the `Host` header. Normally, this will match the SNI part of the ClientHello.

It's likely that the client you are testing with takes the `Host` header you are setting and uses that to set SNI for the TLS handshake, but they are unrelated and don't even need to match.

To illustrate this point, you could use `openssl s_client -connect <server_ip>:443 -servername Test1` and then send the following request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: Test2
```

You will see that you get the certificate for `Test1` before you even make the HTTP request. The server will send a response back from `Test2`. Voila, proof that the `Host` header is not doing what you think it is.

You can abuse NGINX to use an arbitrary header besides Host, but that does not solve the client SNI issue. See this answer for an example of using `proxy_pass` based on the request body, and modify it to use a header instead: [nginx conditional proxy pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878334/nginx-conditional-proxy-pass)